# CAShapeLayer Collision Detection

Tags: objective-c, calayer, uibezierpath, cashapelayer, cgpath

Can anyone will help me with detecting collision/intersection with two different `CAShapeLayer`. As I know it is difficult to do such but not impossible. What will be the idea/logic to achieve the same.

As I have tried `CGRectIntersectsRect` but it is valid for frames only not for `CGPath`.

The following image represent the collision between two `CAShapeLayer`:

[image]

Comment: If you're talking about two shapes with all-straight sides, you can just check to see if (a) any of the vertices of one path fall inside the other's path or (b) if any of the line segments of these two paths intersect with any of the segments of the other path.

Comment: Nice approach, (i) checking if any line of object not intersecting with other object's and (ii) checking if object not containing or not inside other object. Will check if this implementation works.